# Django, update the object after a prefetch_related

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
```

In my views.py, When I want to show the publisher page, I also want to show their books, so I usually do something like this:

```
publisher = Publisher.objects.prefetch_related('book_set').filter(pk=id).first()
```

Then, after some processing I also do some work with the books

```
for book in publisher.book_set.all():
    foo()
```

This works great, but I have one problem. If there is a book added between the query and the for loop, the `publisher.book_set.all()` won't have the newly added books because it was prefetched.

Is there a way to update the publisher object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can delete the entire prefetch cache on the instance:

```
if hasattr(publisher, '_prefetched_objects_cache'):
    del publisher._prefetched_objects_cache
```

If you only want to delete a particular prefetched relation:

```
if hasattr(publisher, '_prefetched_objects_cache'):
    publisher._prefetched_objects_cache.pop('book_set', None)
```

Comment: This accesses Django's internal state which isn't guaranteed to stay stable. I would recommend `refresh_from_db()` as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nicer way to clear prefetched attributes, using only public Django APIs, which is the [`refresh_from_db()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db):

```py
# Reloads all fields from the object as well as clearing prefetched attributes
publisher.refresh_from_db()
# Clears one prefetched attribute, will be re-fetched on next access
publisher.refresh_from_db(fields=['book_set'])

for book in publisher.book_set.all():
```

Answer (score 2):

Also there is possibility to drop all `prefetch_related` from [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

> To clear any prefetch_related behavior, pass None as a parameter::
>
> `non_prefetched = qs.prefetch_related(None)`